# How to apply the Law of total Probability to a joint probability?

Tags: probability

I'm very confused with the application of the [Law of total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to a joint probability.

Suppose I want to figure out the probability that two independent events $X_1$ and $X_2$ will occur at the same time, namely $P(X_1 \wedge X_2)$, and I know there are $n$ events $B_i$ that are mutually exclusive and $\sum_{i=1}^nP(B_i) = 1$.

Since the events are independent 
\begin{align}
  P(X_1 \wedge X_2) = P(X_1)\cdot P(X_2)
\tag{1}
\end{align}

And now, if I understood correctly, the Law of total Probability can be used to calculate $P(X_1)$ and $P(X_2)$:

$$P(X_1) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(X_1|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)$$
$$P(X_2) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(X_2|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
    P(X_1\wedge X_2) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^nP(X_1|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)\right) \cdot 
    \tag{2}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^nP(X_2|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)\right)
\end{align}

So far so good. However, I think I could've also applied the Law of total Probability directly to $P(X_1 \wedge X_2)$

$$ P(X_1 \wedge X_2) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(X_1 \wedge X_2 | A_i)\cdot P(A_i) $$

and then use equation 1 to obtain

\begin{align}
    P(X_1 \wedge X_2) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(X_1|A_i)\cdot P(X_2|A_i) \cdot P(A_i)
    \tag{3}
\end{align}

Equations 2 and 3 seem completely different, which is the source of my confusion, since I was expecting the same result no matter the strategy I chose to compute it.

---

Perhaps the problem is that I can't assume $ P(X_1 \wedge X_2|A_i) = P(X_1|A_i)\cdot P(X_2|A_i) $ from equation 1, but I'm not sure about it. If this is the problem, could someone also explain when does this hold and when it doesn't?

Comment: Indeed the identity $ P(X_1 \wedge X_2|A_i) = P(X_1|A_i)\cdot P(X_2|A_i) $ is not guaranteed by the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (and there is no natural further hypothesis ensuring it holds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps the problem is that I can't assume $\mathsf P(X_1\cap X_2\mid A_i)=\mathsf P(X_1\mid A_i)\cdot\mathsf P(X_2\mid A_i)$ from equation 1, but I'm not sure about it.

That's right, you *cannot* assume that.

Suppose your experiment is to flip two coins.   Let $X_1$ be the event that the first coin is heads, $X_2$ the event that the second coin is heads, and $\{A_0, A_1, A_2\}$ partition the space on the count of heads.

Now we have, $\mathsf P(X_1)=\tfrac 12, \mathsf P(X_2)=\tfrac 12, \mathsf P(X_1\cap X_2)=\tfrac 1 4$, so the events $X_1, X_2$ are independent.

However, $\mathsf P(X_1\mid A_0)=0, \mathsf P(X_2\mid A_0)=0, \mathsf P(X_1\cap X_2\mid A_0)=0 \\ \mathsf P(X_1\mid A_1)=\tfrac 1 2, \mathsf P(X_2\mid A_1)=\tfrac 1 2, \mathsf P(X_1\cap X_2\mid A_1)=0 \\ \mathsf P(X_1\mid A_2)=1, \mathsf P(X_2\mid A_2)=1, \mathsf P(X_1\cap X_2\mid A_2)=1$

So clearly, conditional independence given a partition, is *not* guaranteed by the independence of the events.